# Cassandra Error: TNegotiatingServerTransport.java:508 - Failed to open server transport

Tags: cassandra, datastax

We are seeing this error on our production Data-center. What's caused this error/What does it indicate.

```
ERROR [Thrift:5] 2019-03-07 23:34:25,007  TNegotiatingServerTransport.java:508 - Failed to open server transport.
org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
ERROR [Thrift:5] 2019-03-07 23:34:25,007  CustomTThreadPoolServer.java:225 - Error occurred during processing of message.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to open server transport: unknown
```

Comment: What version are you running? thrifts been deprecated for years

Comment: Datastax: dse 5.1.3

Answer (score 0):

this is a sign that node could be overloaded most probably due high number of the Thrift connections - you need to check your logs why this happened, could be OOM, or something like. Or simply not enough threads available to start a new one (check system limits on the max proc, for example).

DataStax support knowledge base has [corresponding article](https://support.datastax.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002268006-High-number-of-connections-can-exhaust-available-native-threads-for-Cassandra-JVM) with more links, etc.

P.S. 5.1.3 is very old - it's recommended to upgrade to latest versions to get latest fixes, etc.

Comment: With my understanding DSE 5.1.3, thrift port that was using by Cassandra was 9160. But none of my applications are connecting through that port.

Comment: The message looks like that somebody tried to connect to it - maybe network scanning or something like?

Comment: Thanks for the update, FYI: we have scheduled a cronjob with netstat command to see if any thing is connecting to that port during some period of time where we observed frequently that error message. Will try tcpdump if it doesn't help. Let me know if there is any thing else i can try.